# change color of title of af:document in jsf page of ADF

Tags: css, jsf, title, oracle-adf

I have created a jsf page using af:document with title(which is required) but by default this tile is coming with black color due to default skin but i need it red.

I tried with inline CSS but it didn't work.code snippets is below:

```
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
    <af:document title="#{bundle['XXSG_OSA_CANCEL_ORDER']}" id="d1"
                 inlineStyle="background-color:#F7F7F8;background-image:none;color:red;font-weight:normal;"
                 styleClass="color-set">
        <af:messages id="m1" inlineStyle="background-color:#F7F7F8;color:red;font-weight:normal;"/>
        <af:form id="f1" inlineStyle="background-color:#F7F7F8;">
```

Can anyone tell me if there is a key  which can be override in SKIN to change the title of af:document?

Code of the pop-up (of JSF page) which is used in another page:

```html
<div id="j_id16" class="x1d3">
   <div class="x1ee" data-afr-panelwindowbackground="1" style="display: none;"></div>
   <div class="x1ee" data-afr-panelwindowbackground="1" style="display: none;"></div>
   <div class="x1ee" data-afr-panelwindowbackground="1" style="display: none;"></div>
   <div class="x1ee" data-afr-panelwindowbackground="1" style="display: none;"></div>
   <table summary="" role="presentation" class="x1dj" data-afr-shaddec="sd$4" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td class="p_AFResizable x1d8" id="j_id16::_hse">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="p_AFResizable x1da" id="j_id16::_hce">
               <table style="cursor:default" summary="" role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                           <div id="j_id16::_ticn" class="x1e6" style="display:none"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="x1dl" id="j_id16::tb" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
                           <div id="j_id16::_ttxt" class="x17g">Order Cancellation</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <div class="x1e8"><a aria-label="Close" href="#" onclick="return false" class="x17e" id="j_id16::close" title="Close"></a></div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </td>
            <td class="p_AFResizable x1dc" id="j_id16::_hee">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="p_AFResizable x1dq" id="j_id16::_cse">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="p_AFResizable x1dn" id="j_id16::contentContainer" tabindex="-1">
               <div id="j_id16::_ccntr" class="x1do" style="width:400px;height:300px;position:relative;overflow:hidden;">
                  <div id="j_id17" class="xt4 " style="position:absolute;width:auto;height:auto;top:0px;left:0px;bottom:0px;right:0px"><iframe id="j_id17::f" title="Content" src="/osaportal/faces/adf.dialog-request?_rtrnId=1496388287220&amp;_afrPage=s2" onload="AdfDhtmlInlineFramePeer.__iframeLoadHandler(event)" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%" _adfloaded="1" data-afr-panelwindowid="j_id16" data-afr-rtnid="1496388287220" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
               </div>
            </td>
            <td class="p_AFResizable x1ds" id="j_id16::_cee">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="p_AFResizable x1du" id="j_id16::_fse">
               <div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="p_AFResizable x1dv" id="j_id16::_fce">
               <table summary="" role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="p_AFResizable x1dy" id="j_id16::_fcc"></td>
                        <td valign="bottom" align="left">
                           <div class="p_AFResizable x1e3"><a tabindex="-1" class="x1e1" id="j_id16::_ree" title="Resize"></a></div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </td>
            <td class="p_AFResizable x1dw" id="j_id16::_fee">
               <div></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Property "title" used to set page title (name displayed in browser tab). If you have a text title on your page also, it must be something else.

Comment: Actually we are using this page as a pop up on some another jsff page where this title is coming on the pop up and we want to change the color of title.

Comment: Get to your's browser developer tools and check, and post html code for this popup title here.

Comment: @Nagh I have added the HTML code in question where title is "Order Cancellation". Please help me as i need it in Red color. in case you need any more information, please let me know

Comment: You need to set ( if not exists, create it) org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.DISABLE_CONTENT_COMPRESSION to true in WEB-INF/web.xml. Don't forget to set it false in production enviroment.
Paste popup html code after that. Also I need to know, do you use custom skin already?

Comment: Yes i am using custom skin as well as common CSS file for style class

Comment: Did you try "color:red !important" ?

Comment: This issue is resolved by changing the skin property of panelwindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved by changing the skin property of **af|panelWindow::title** where i can change the color title for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the color of the title in the window bar (where things like minimize/maximize icons are)?
I think this is controlled at the client machine windows os level, not at the ADF level.

Comment: I am using this page in another page as a Pop up and i have added the generated HTML code in question and i need that pop up title in Red color.